# JQuery - One handler for multiple elements using variables

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, handler

I have two variables defined like this:

```
var $a = $('#a'),
    $b = $('#b');
```

How can I rewrite the following line using $a and $b?

```
$('#a, #b').click(function(e){...});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$([$a.get(0), $b.get(0)]).click(function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use $('#a, #b').click() along with $a, $b then?

Comment: Absolutely, much better, but I thought you don't want to do that and ask how to do it assuming you already have the $a and $b variables.

Comment: Keep in mind this only works on $a and $b's first element. If you change $a or $b to a selector that returns more then one element only the first will be bound. But I agree with Darin $('#a, #b') is a better solution if you only use them once.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a.add($b).click(function(e){...});
```

`add` returns a new node set holding the union.  $b can be "pretty much anything that $() accepts."

Answer (score 0):

It seems you ca do just this:

```
$(deleteBtn).add(copyBtn).add(moveBtn).click(function(){});
```

As it says here http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score -1):

Depends of what you want to do next with your vars.

You could just define them as one:

```
var $a = $('#a, #b');
$a.click()
```

Or use them separately:

```
/* This way the click event is applied even if each selector returns
   more then one element. And $a and $b is preserved */
$([].concat($a.toArray()).concat($b.toArray())).click(function () {
    console.log(this)
});
```

**EDIT**

Updated code.

..fredrik

Comment: No, they're not equivalent.  The second will make `$b` the context.

Comment: No, the second parameter ($b) is the context.

Comment: I did a test case: var a = $('div'), b = $('span'); $(a,b).click(function { console.log(this) }); console only returns div's.

Comment: your example isn't complete.  But read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) on the main function, and it's clear which parameter is which.