# How do I call a jQuery function on several jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine you have the following three jQuery objects `a, b, c,` how would you for example set identical attributes on all of them without repeating too much code as I'm currently doing:

```
a.attr({
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
});
b.attr({
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
});
c.attr({
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
});
```

Isn't there something like:

```
$(a, b, c).attr({
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
});
```

?

**EDIT**: Now that I learned I can either use `.add()` or `$()` with an array of non-jQuery objects, I wonder why `$(a, b, c)` isn't supported because the other solutions to me seem unnecessarily verbose or convoluted.

Comment: Couldn't you just try what you posted to see if it works?

Comment: And what did you just do?

Comment: @user511287 you might be also interested in the jQuery's `.add()` method. Take a look at the DOCS

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: No, what the OP listed doesn't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder huh it doesn't? then I apparently _did_ try that!

Comment: Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966678/jquery-one-handler-for-multiple-elements-using-variables

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, in the link above you can see that P has already defined it's jQuery elements, than he tries to apply a method to them. Cannot see any difference. The only difference from your answer and the already answered one is `.attr` -vs- `.click` (If I'm not missing something crucial here.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Ah, yes, sorry -- but in a very limited context (jQuery objects containing one object), and the top-voted answer relies on that. There is an answer, futher down, which discusses `.add`, though. (Not the other options available.)

Comment: Re your edit, I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: _"EDIT: Now that I learned I can either use .add() or $() with an array of non-jQuery objects, I wonder why $(a, b, c) isn't supported"_ See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0ea8c32863af31fb5cfc184e8d513bbae35583e8/src/core/init.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't there something like:
>
> `$(a, b, c).attr({`...

No, but you have two similar choices:

- `.add` (this is probably the simplest and clearest)
- `$()` on an **array** of elements

Here's `add`:

```js
var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c");
a.add(b).add(c).css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

Here's `$()` on an array of elements:

```js
var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c");
$(a.get().concat(b.get()).concat(c.get())).css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

Or if you **know** there's only one element in each jQuery object, then it's a bit simpler:

```js
var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c");
$([a[0], b[0], c[0]]).css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

---

> I wonder why `$(a, b, c).foo()` isn't supported because the other solutions to me seem unnecessarily verbose or convoluted.

The `$()` function is already **ridiculously** overloaded ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery)), my guess is that's the only reason this hasn't been added at some point. It's also surprising how rarely this comes up.

Comment: Doesn't jQuery also take `$([a, b, c])`?

Comment: @user2864740: No. It *will* take an array, but if you give it an array of jQuery objects you don't get what you want. If `a`, `b`, and `c` were just DOM elements, that would work.

Comment: Wouldn't making `$(a, b, c).attr({...` work be a useful and good addition to jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966678/jquery-one-handler-for-multiple-elements-using-variables

Comment: Regarding duplicate: What T.J.Crowder said

Comment: @user511287 I guess if you had a good use case, probably. My opinion is that if you are doing something that creates and performs actions on individual jQuery objects but then needs to do an action on all of them, you probably can refactor your code to a cleaner solution that eliminates the need.

Comment: @user511287 **Identical duplicates**. the only difference is in the method that afterwards applies. The question states correctly: how to group already defined jQuery Element Objects and apply a method to all of them.   You method is `.attr`, while in the other Q the method is `.click` but that never minds. It's the way to use `.add()` or other tricks. So yes, it's a duplicate question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Not really identical, see [my note here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304909/how-do-i-call-a-jquery-function-on-several-jquery-objects/29305055?noredirect=1#comment46805581_29304909). But yes, **very** similar.

Comment: Regarding my edit, fair point. And to me it also seems curious this hasn't been asked more often yet (specifically)

Answer (score 0):

`$.each([a,b,c], function (index, item) {// do stuff here with item});`

Comment: Could you also explain your solution?

Comment: @magnilex check out: api.jquery.com/each

Comment: It is not for me. Short answers, like this one, automatically goes into a review queue for "low quality posts". I am not saying your answer is of low quality, but it will get better if you explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var a = $("#a"), b = $("#b"), c = $("#c");

var attrs = {
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
};

$([]).pushStack([a[0], b[0], c[0]]).attr(attrs)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

---

alternatively

```js
var a = $("#a"), b = $("#b"), c = $("#c");

var attrs = {
    "first":  "sameFirst",
    "second": "sameSecond",
    "third":  "sameThird",
};

$([a, b, c]).map(function() {
  $(this).attr(attrs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

Comment: thanks also works often, but that relies on `a, b, c` originating from simple selectors which can be easily repeated all over the place, which isn't necessarily true

Comment: Not certain if interpret _"but that relies on a, b, c originating from simple selectors which can be easily repeated all over the place, which isn't necessarily true "_ ?   correctly ?  Would `a`, `b`, `c` be cached selectors ?

Comment: @guest271314: No, they'd be what the question **says** they are: jQuery objects.

Comment: @guest271314 `a,b,c` are just jQuery objects, you don't know where they come from (not necessariy from single DOM elements with ids `a`, `b`, `c`) therefore `$("#a, #b, #c")` generally doesn't work

Comment: @guest271314 works too, but not as simple as the proposals above